# Recuperar a imagem do facebook maior pelo ID

Tags: php, html, facebook

Preciso recuperar a imagem do perfil do Facebook, ja achei um código, porem a imagem vem pequena, alguém sabe algum código onde eu consiga recuperar ela maio?

Não posso utilizar a API do facebook, pois os ID's, ja etão cadastrados no banco do cliente, so preciso aumentar a foto

`http://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{{id}}/picture`

[Link](http://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/100002718140269/picture)

Comment: digita depois do link acima `?type=large`, mas não fica tão grande assim. Mas melhor que essa minuscula.

Comment: Sei que pelo sdk do próprio facebook você faz essa solicitação e informa, através de parâmetros, o tamanho que deseja. Algo assim: `facebook.api('/me/picture?height=180&width=180')`

Comment: Ja ajuda dimais colocando o ?type=large, valew flavio, eu queria utilizar a API, mais não vai adianta, o cadastro ja tem mais de 1500 usuários somente com o ID, e o cliente não quer reformular o sistema, 

Vou tentar convencer ele heheh, mais esta solução ja ajudou dimais

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o seguinte serviço:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{{id}}/picture?type=large
```